# How to save the state in Localstorage?

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage, navbar

Good morning who is reading this message!

I'm still relatively new to programming and I have a question... I made a Navigation bar: body > div > nav > div > ul > li*10

I have the movement done in CSS

```
 //Barra de Navegacion
  const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

  function activeLink(){
    list.forEach((item)=>
    item.classList.remove('active'));
    this.classList.add('active');
  
  if(list.classlist.contains('active')){
    localStorage.setItem('on','true');
  } else{
   localStorage.setItem('on','false');
  }
  };
  
  if (localStorage.getItem('on') === 'true'){
    list.classList.add('active');
            
  } else {
    list.classList.remove('active');
    
  };


  list.forEach((item)=>
  item.addEventListener('click',activeLink));
```

The problem is that when I refresh the page or go to another part of it, it does not save the changes. how could i do it with localstorage?

I tried several ways and I can't find the way to do it

Thank you very much in advance!

[image]

[VIDEO VIDEO VIDEO VIDEO VIDEO](https://youtu.be/mhbpOsFNJPM)

Comment: What did you try?  Any way you look at it, the process is always the same.  Any data you want to persist outside of the page, save it somewhere (e.g. local storage).  When the page loads, look for that data and respond to it accordingly.  What attempt did you make to save your data, retrieve your data, use your data, etc. and in your debugging what specifically didn't work in that attempt?

Comment: Please provide the HTML too.

Comment: Also, `list.classList.add/remove/contains()` should give an error, because list is an `HTMLCollection`

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that using localStorage is the right way to achieve what you want to do. I suggest that each page should have its link highlighted when you open it. This can be achieved by adding classes manually to the link of each page, keeping in my mind it wouldn't be that many links in the navigation.

Comment: Can you please share some code to make your answer clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is too far down.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('on') === 'true'){
  list.classList.add('active');
} else {
    list.classList.remove('active');
};
```

You should set this set immediatly when the page loads, immediatly after

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
```

So the list has the correct class from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with this part of the code, but the syntax you are using is correct. Here is some example of usage of the [local storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to repeat.

You can save key-value pair to the local storage using the syntax:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

You can retrieve the saved value with the following syntax:

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```

If you still can't get the code to work correctly you can try to open your browser's developer tools and look at the storage. If your developer's tools are saying that there are no entries saved to the local storage you then know that the main problem is with saving the key-value pair.

Here's how to open the developer tools in Chrome:

- First press F12 on your keyboard (or Ctrl+Shift+J)
- Follow the steps shown in the image below

[image]

If you still cannot get the code working you should check your browser settings to make sure there are no security settings enabled that are preventing your application from saving to the local storage.